# QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER in teradata

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

below is the oracle SQL and i want to change it in Teradata format.

```
SELECT branch_code,
    branch_no,
    c_no,
    cd_type
FROM (
    SELECT branch_code,
        branch_no,
        c_no,
        cd_type,
        * * RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY c_no ORDER BY cd_type
            ) RANK * *
    FROM (
        SELECT branch_code,
            branch_no,
            c_no,
            MIN(cd_type) cd_type
        FROM EMPLOYEE
        WHERE S_CODE = 'C'
            AND (branch_no) NOT IN (
                SELECT branch_code
                FROM DEPARTMENT
                WHERE branch_code = 'ABC'
                )
        )
    )
WHERE RANK = 1
```

I have used QUALIFY for RANK as below .

```
SELECT branch_code,
    branch_no,
    c_no,
    cd_type
FROM (
    SELECT branch_code,
        branch_no,
        c_no,
        cd_type,
        * * QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY c_no ORDER BY cd_type
            ) * * RANK
    FROM (
        SELECT branch_code,
            branch_no,
            c_no,
            MIN(cd_type) cd_type
        FROM EMPLOYEE
        WHERE S_CODE = 'C'
            AND (branch_no) NOT IN (
                SELECT branch_code
                FROM DEPARTMENT
                WHERE branch_code = 'ABC'
                )
        )
    )
WHERE RANK = 1
```

But getting error that "Expected something between , and QUALIFY.

Can we put QUALIFY in select statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably simplified your existing query as this is no valid Oracle SQL (there's no GROUP BY in the Inline View). Plus you compare `branch_no` to `branch_code`in the NOT IN.

Otherwise Ed Gibbs' answer can be further simplified to:

```
SELECT branch_code,
    branch_no,
    c_no,
    MIN(cd_type) cd_type
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE S_CODE = 'C'
    AND (branch_no) NOT IN (
        SELECT branch_no
        FROM DEPARTMENT
        WHERE branch_code = 'ABC'
        )
GROUP BY branch_code,
    branch_no,
    c_no
QUALIFY
   RANK()
   OVER (PARTITION BY c_no 
         ORDER BY MIN(cd_type) = 1
```

If `branch_no` is defined as NULLable you should also rewrite `NOT IN` to `NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 2):

Normally, analytic values like `RANK` are calculated second to last, after joining and filtering and `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`. The only thing done after analytic values is `ORDER BY`. That's why in Oracle you need to put the `RANK` into an inner query and then test its value in an outer query. In Teradata, `QUALIFY` is executed after the analytic functions and before the `ORDER BY`, meaning you don't need the outer query to test the `RANK` value.

I don't have access to Teradata today, so this query isn't tested but I like to think it's close:

```
SELECT branch_code,
    branch_no,
    c_no,
    cd_type
FROM (
    SELECT branch_code,
        branch_no,
        c_no,
        MIN(cd_type) cd_type
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE S_CODE = 'C'
        AND (branch_no) NOT IN (
            SELECT branch_code
            FROM DEPARTMENT
            WHERE branch_code = 'ABC'
        )
)
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c_no ORDER BY cd_type) = 1
```